# What does the y-axis of a normal distribution represent?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

In a `normal distribution` ,as far as I know distribution represents `frequency` of sth.But then how come `normal distribution` y-axis becomes

[image]

If distribution y-axis doesnt represent `frequency`, the what is `central limit theorem`.The `central limit theorem` y-axis represents the `frequency` of mean samples.Shouldnt it represent the above formula to satisfy a `normal distribution`

Comment: What? Normal distribution doesn't represent frequency on the y-axis, but rather density. Frequency only works for discrete distributions. CLT is unrelated here.

Comment: The central limit theorem says, the sample means frequncy if plotted will follow normal distrbution.So y-axis represents no of samples ryt? or does it represent the above formula?

Comment: No, we use the CLT to estimate the distribution of the mean. But the mean is a continuous variable and so will also be distributed on the real line ${\rm I\!R}$. Which means you will also get a density, not frequency.

Comment: But central limit theorem says we plot frequency in y-axis ryt?

Comment: You really need to understand probability densities and distribution functions before you can understand what the central limit theorem says

Comment: There are two distinct questions here, so I have provided links to threads that answer each one separately.  There are many other posts on this site that speak to the issues raised in this question: consider conducting a search.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the definition of the normal density, it is not dimension-less, but its measurment unit (*dimension* in the physical meaning) is the same as that of $1/\sigma$ which in turn is the same dimension as that of $1/x$. Integrating over $f(x)$ yields a dimensionless quantity: the probability of the region of integration.

The y-axis is thus "probabilty per measurement unit of x". This holds for *every* probability density, not only the normal density.